# Too Many Before_Filter Validations?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, admin

**Is there such thing as "too many validators"?**

The reason I ask is because I am currently using Devise and already have implemented the:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

In my Location controller, for the show view, I must also validate the person trying to view it is the owner:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_location_owner!, only: [:show]
```

Now last, but not least, currently, my users are not allowed to create "Locations". They are created by us, the admins for now, and then assigned.

Third possible before_filter validator:

```
 before_filter :authorized_access?, except: [:show]
```

This concept is clustering my controller and does not look quite right. However, it is what I need to achieve and works fine.

Is this classified as "okay" in Rails programming?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your before_filters in the appropriate controllers and in an appropriate way. It is perfectly acceptable to have multiple before_filters and there is no reason why you wouldn't want these three filters.

As long as these methods are efficient (i.e by using Devise's `current_user` rather than looking up the user each time) then I can see no reason to improve your code.

Comment: And that is exactly how I am implementing the validators. Thank you for your input!